# Why can't numpy.cross produce correct answer for multi-dimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

u = np.array([[195, 8, 9]], np.uint8)
v = np.array([250, 166, 68], np.int)
result1 = np.cross(v, u.astype(int))
result2 = np.cross(v, u)
result3 = np.cross(v, u[0])
print(result1, result2, result3)
```

output is

```
[[   950  11010 -30370]] [[182   2  94]] [   950  11010 -30370]
```

Why cant `np.cross(v,u)` produce correct answer, but `np.cross(v,u[0])` can ?
All results dtypes are numpy.int32

I'm using python 3.9.2 and numpy 1.20.1 .

Comment: Huh... that looks like a NumPy bug.

Comment: What is the result you're expecting?

Comment: @Terra Should be [[   950  11010 -30370]] [[   950  11010 -30370]] [   950  11010 -30370]

Comment: I agree with @user2357112supportsMonica--this is a bug in `cross`.  Note that `np.array([950, 11010, -30370]) % 256` is `array([182,   2,  94])`. NumPy casting of types between a scalar and array is different from casting two arrays, and this difference has an efffect in the behavior of the code in [`cross`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9fcc13258960adb94d7dda0b478c0997763d4c4d/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1479).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I wouldn't say it's a bug, numpy has a promote_types function that casts to which both arrays can be safely cast and it is used in np.cross as well. So the calculation in case #2 is actullay performed in np.uint8. If you change v to contain a float for example v=[250. , 166, 68] you should get the correct results. - Oh right, it returns a correct answer for case #3. Yeah, it's a bug, my bad :D

Comment: I would call it a bug--otherwise the user has to know details of the implementation to understand why `np.cross(v, u)` gives the unexpected result while `np.cross([v], u)` gives the expected result.  Also, it is a sign that something went wrong when the function returns an array with data type `int64` but still does an internal calculation with type `uint8`.